# Why can not I remove the react-native? How to completely remove react-native?

Tags: react-native, npm, uninstallation

Why can not I remove the react-native? How to completely remove react-native?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to use below command for uninstalling the react-native:

```
$ npm uninstall -g npm
```

For more clarification, please refer [this link.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli)

You might need to use `sudo` along as well so it can get required permission to uninstall from all sections.

Comment: I used sudo did not help

Comment: why remove npm?